# How to stop an IntentService when it has a SensorListener running

Tags: listener, sensors, intentservice

I'm running an IntentService which has a SensorListener running. It seems impossible to stop the service from another activity within the app.

Is there anyway at all to stop an IntentService from outside the service?

Also, since the Listener is the only thing that is running (keeping the app from stopping), is it possible to unregister the Listener from another activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's ok now. Commonsware told me here

[BroadcastReceiver within a Service not receiving broadcasts Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638142/broadcastreceiver-within-a-service-not-receiving-broadcasts-android)

that I was leaking the receiver, hence the appearance of the service not being stoppable.. IntentService cannot implement receivers